# Using DUB package with existing code

Tags: git, d, dub

I'd like to use a DUB package library written by someone else with some existing d source code of my own. My existing source has been using Git, and has not been using DUB.

I'd like to continue using the same Git repo after incorporating the DUB package.

I've tried various settings in dub.json, but none seem to work with this situation. I'd hate to do a dub init, then manually copy everything over and link back to my Git repo.

What is my best option?

Comment: Are you trying to switch your project over to using dub?  Or just use the dub library in you package without using dub to do the compiling of yourown code.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Please post in detail what you have tried, your Dub configuration, the directory layout of your project, the error messages you have been getting, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to use the library, you can clone it and pass it to the compiler when compiling using `-I`, read more [here](https://dlang.org/dmd-linux.html)

If you want to add `dub` support to your project, just create a `source` directory, copy your project into it and create a `dub.json` file, plus rename your entry point file to `app.d`, or change the entry file in the `dub.json`, you can read more about that [here](https://dub.pm/package-format-json.html)